# Requested Java Version for Hazelcast 3.7 and higher

Tags: hazelcast

I am working in the migration of one application using Hazelcast 2.6.9 towards latest stable Hazelcast 3.7.4 version.

The application with HZ 2.6.9 runs at this moment using Java 1.6:

java version "1.6.0_38"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode)

I have been looking into HZ 3.7.4 Training Bundle documentation, and I have seen reference to JVM: JDK 6,7,8 Oracle JDK, but I am not sure about concrete version of required Java 6, concretely if HZ 3.7.4 will continue running with 1.6.0_38

Thanks a lot

Regards,
Jorge

Answer (score 1):

You can very well go for Java 1.8 but that documentation meant, it is backward compatible upto Java 1.6

We are currently using Hazelcast 3.6.2 running on Java 1.8 in production for past one year without any issues.